# How to make encoding consistent across the 2d array

Tags: python, scikit-learn

When I use [OrdinalEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html) from [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/) it makes an independent mapping for each column. In my case each entry is a letter so if there is one extra letter in a column that doesn't occur in another column the encodings are different.  How can you make a single consistent encoding for the entire matrix/2d array?

Here is a function that takes in a list of strings (each of the same length) and returns the encoded matrix and encoder:

```
def makeX(words):
    enc = OrdinalEncoder()
    X = []
    for i in range(len(mylist)):
        X.append(list(mylist[i]))
    X = enc.fit_transform(X)
    return X, enc
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] representing the problem and a desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Lets take dataframe with two words as columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(
[['h', 'h'],
 ['e' ,'o'],
 ['l', 'w'],
 ['l' ,'d'],
 ['o' ,'y']]))
df
    0   1
0   h   h
1   e   o
2   l   w
3   l   d
4   o   y
```

To have a uniform encoding, you can concat the columns to a single column

```
temp = pd.concat([df[0], df[1]]).to_frame()
temp
    0
0   h
1   e
2   l
3   l
4   o
0   h
1   o
2   w
3   d
4   y
```

and then apply the encoder. Thereafter, you can split the column into multiple columns based on the index to get the expected columns (this step you can do in multiple ways which are in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66156997/pandas-get-original-dataframe-after-vertical-concatenation))

```
temp[0] = OrdinalEncoder().fit_transform(temp[0].to_frame())
temp
    0
0   2.0
1   1.0
2   3.0
3   3.0
4   4.0
0   2.0
1   4.0
2   5.0
3   0.0
4   6.0

pd.DataFrame(temp.groupby(level=0)[0].apply(list).to_numpy().tolist())

    0   1
0   2.0 2.0
1   1.0 4.0
2   3.0 5.0
3   3.0 0.0
4   4.0 6.0
```