# pandas get original dataframe after vertical concatenation

Tags: python, pandas

Let us take a sample dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10).reshape((5,2)))
df
    0   1
0   0   1
1   2   3
2   4   5
3   6   7
4   8   9
```

and concatenate the two columns into a single column

```
temp = pd.concat([df[0], df[1]]).to_frame()
temp
    0
0   0
1   2
2   4
3   6
4   8
0   1
1   3
2   5
3   7
4   9
```

What would be the most efficient way to get the original dataframe i.e `df` from `temp`?
The following way using `groupby` works. But is there any more efficient way (like without `groupby`-`apply`, `pivot`) to do this whole task from concatenation (and then doing some operation) and then reverting back to the original dataframe?

```
pd.DataFrame(temp.groupby(level=0)[0]
             .apply(list)
             .to_numpy().tolist())
```

Answer (score 2):

I think we can do `pivot` after assign the column value with `cumcount`

```
check = temp.assign(c=temp.groupby(level=0).cumcount()).pivot(columns='c',values='0')
Out[66]: 
c  0  1
0  0  1
1  2  3
2  4  5
3  6  7
4  8  9
```

Comment: @ShubhamSharma I think they just want to remove it due to the overlap with melt and stack ~

Answer (score 1):

You can use `groupby` + `cumcount` to create a sequential counter per `level=0` group then append it to the index of the dataframe and use `unstack` to reshape:

```
temp.set_index(temp.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), append=True)[0].unstack()
```

---

```
   0  1
0  0  1
1  2  3
2  4  5
3  6  7
4  8  9
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10).reshape((5,2)))

temp = pd.concat([df[0], df[1]]).to_frame()

duplicated_index = temp.index.duplicated()

pd.concat([temp[~duplicated_index], temp[duplicated_index]], axis=1)
```

Works for this specific case (as pointed out in the comments, it will fail if you have more than one set of duplicate index values) so I don't think it's a better solution.

Comment: I checked the timings for all the solutions.This seems to be the fastest way to go for this and seems like quite generic. Does anyone think it may fail in any of the scenarios? @Beny , ShubhamSharma, Mayank?

Comment: @ggaurav It will fail if you have multiple set of duplicates. In this case, there is only 1 set of duplicate indexes. If you have more, it will fail. You can try.

Comment: Thanks @MayankPorwal, didn't think it through. But I was looking for a solution that is without groupby or pivot.

Comment: @MayankPorwal point is why I said it wasn't a better solution! Sorry, should have been more clear as to why it only works in this specific case.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
In [1267]: temp['g'] = temp.groupby(level=0)[0].cumcount()
In [1273]: temp.pivot(columns='g', values=0)
Out[1279]: 
g  0  1
0  0  1
1  2  3
2  4  5
3  6  7
4  8  9
```

**OR:**

```
In [1281]: temp['g'] = (temp.index == 0).cumsum() - 1

In [1282]: temp.pivot(columns='g', values=0)
Out[1282]: 
g  0  1
0  0  1
1  2  3
2  4  5
3  6  7
4  8  9
```